# Yeoman generator: how do I access user supplied options?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm building a yeoman generator. I prompt the user to name the project like this:

```
SimplesiteGenerator.prototype.askFor = function askFor() {
    var cb = this.async();


    console.log(this.yeoman);

    var prompts = [{
        name: 'siteName',
        message: 'What do you want to call your site?'
    }];

    this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
        this.siteName = props.siteName;

        cb();
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Further on, I build the file system:

```
SimplesiteGenerator.prototype.app = function app() {
    this.mkdir( 'app');
    this.mkdir('app/templates');
    this.mkdir( 'img');
```

I'd like to build the filesystem within a directory that is given the same name as the project. How do I get the user-supplied option and pass it into app ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an empty global variable, then assign it the value of the users answer like so

```
var projectFolderName = '';

this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
    this.siteName = props.siteName;

     projectFolderName = props.siteName;

    cb();
}.bind(this));
```

Then inject this variable into your build path string via concatenation like so

```
SimplesiteGenerator.prototype.app = function app() {
    this.mkdir( 'app/' + projectFolderName);
    this.mkdir('app/templates');
    this.mkdir( 'img');
}
```